# Convexity of problem with inverse matrix

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I am trying to solve the next problem
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{P}{\text{maximize}}
& & \log \det P \\
& \text{subject to}
& & A^T P^{-1} + P^{-1} A \preceq 0 \\
&&& P^{-1} \succeq 0 \\
&&& \ldots
\end{aligned}

Is this problem convex or can be transfrom to convex?

I try to introduce the new variable Q

\begin{aligned}
& \underset{P}{\text{maximize}}
& & \log \det P \\
& \text{subject to}
& & A^T Q + P Q \preceq 0 \\
&&& Q \succeq 0 \\
&&& P Q = I
&&& \ldots
\end{aligned}
but last constrainst is BMI.

Comment: $\log(\det(P))$ is convex on the set of $P$ which are positive-semi-definite and $\det(P)\neq 0$.

Comment: No, log(det(P)) is concave on the positive definite cone

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Removed my incorrect answer.

However, it is trivial/ill-posed due to the homogenous form you use. If there exist a feasible solution ($A$ stable) you can let $P$ tend to infinity and obtain an arbitrarily good solution)

Comment: Can't we multiply the constraints on the left and right by P?

Comment: Doh! Of course. Read the question too fast and thought this was what had been tried with $Q$

Comment: Thanks for answer, but there is other constraints. I try to find an ellipsoid with maximum volume inside the region of attraction. But this problem is likely nonconvex.

Comment: Indeed, if you have other constraints on $P$ that cannot be expressed in terms of $P^{-1}$, then it is nonconvex. This suggests that finding the *minimum* volume ellipsoid is convex, then, and that is of course not going to be useful to you.

Comment: You would have to specify what you mean more precisely. This is a linear system so the region of attraction in $R^n$. Do you mean the largest invariant ellipsoid such that linear constraints on the states hold, or something like that?

Comment: I train with SOS-decomposition and finding ROA of nonlinear systems. The simplest case: we have the quadratic Lyapunov function from linearized system $A^T P + P A = -Q$, 
then find $\gamma$ such that $\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^n : V(x) \le \gamma \rbrace \subseteq \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \dot V \le 0 \rbrace$ using polynomial S-procedure.
The volume of finding ellipsoid depend of choose Q, and I try to maximize it. It's quite meaningless problem.

Comment: OK. There is a plethora of papers on that topic (just google sum-of-squares ROA). As you will see, it is typically not convex, so various hacks are done to solve the problem approximately.